# Having trouble with Jquery event.drag together with other jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having quite a bit of a problem here, check out [this Website here](http://testsiteproject.bugs3.com). When I click on the grey button it will show, and if I click on it again it will hide. But if I drag (on drag start) the button to reveal the content I can no longer click to open or close, I don't now whats wrong. When I inspect the code and click the button I can see that .nursebutton changes its value (from 0 -> 275 and -275 -> 0). I don't know what might cause the function `slideNurse()` from not executing proberly.

I'm using the "expansion" [jquery.event.drag](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag#properties) together with other Jquery, perhaps its this that is the problem? Have any one of you guys ever encontered this problem? Do you have a clever alternative sollution to my problem? I want both the drag functionality and the "on click" function animation.

below is the jquery code.

Thanks =)

```
var showing = false;
jQuery(function($){
var $div = $('#container');
  $('.nursebutton')
      .drag("start",function( ev, dd ){
         dd.limit = $div.offset();
         dd.limit.right = dd.limit.left + $div.outerWidth() - $( this ).outerWidth();              
      })
      .drag(function( ev, dd ){
         $( this ).css({
            left: Math.min( dd.limit.right, Math.max( dd.limit.left, dd.offsetX ) )

         });
         $('#nurseView').css({
            left: Math.min( dd.limit.right, Math.max( dd.limit.left, dd.offsetX ) )
        });
      })
      .drag("end",function(ev, dd ){
         var treshold = dd.offsetX;
         var menu = $('#nurseView');
         if(treshold>1712){
                $("#nurseView").animate({"left": "1872px"}, "fast");
                $(".nursebutton").animate({"left": "1872px"}, "fast");
         }
         else{
            $("#nurseView").animate({"left": "1595px"}, "fast");
            $(".nursebutton").animate({"left": "1595px"}, "fast");
         }               
      });
});

function slideNurse(){//This function works before I "activate thejquery function above
    if (!showing) {
        showing = true;
        $("#nurseView").animate({"right": "+=275px"}, "slow");
        $(".nursebutton").animate({"right": "+=275px"}, "slow");
    } else {
        showing = false;
        $("#nurseView").animate({"right": "-=275px"}, "slow");
        $(".nursebutton").animate({"right": "-=275px"}, "slow");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed the jquery code as the one below and it worked (Well not perfectly, the first time it screws up so there I had to add a boolean to keep track of if its the first time its runned or not)

```
var showing = false;
var first = false;
    jQuery(function($){
    var $div = $('#DragNursecontainer');
      $('.nursebutton')
            .click(function(){
                if(first ==true){
            if (!showing) {
                showing = true;
                $("#nurseView").animate({"left": "1595px"}, "fast");
                $(".nursebutton").animate({"left": "1595px"}, "fast");
            } else {
                showing = false;
                $("#nurseView").animate({"left": "1872px"}, "fast");
                $(".nursebutton").animate({"left": "1872px"}, "fast");
            }
                }
                else{
                    first = true;

                if (!showing) {
                showing = true;
                $("#nurseView").hide(5);
                $("#nurseView").animate({"left": "1595px"}, "fast");
                $("#nurseView").show(5);
                $(".nursebutton").hide(5);
                $(".nursebutton").animate({"left": "1595px"}, "fast");
                $(".nursebutton").show(5);
                } else {
                showing = false;
                $("#nurseView").animate({"left": "1872px"}, "fast");
                $(".nursebutton").animate({"left": "1872px"}, "fast");
                }   //slideNurse();
                }
          })
          .drag("start",function( ev, dd ){
             dd.limit = $div.offset();
             dd.limit.right = dd.limit.left + $div.outerWidth() - $( this ).outerWidth();              
          })
          .drag(function( ev, dd ){
             $( this ).css({
                left: Math.min( dd.limit.right, Math.max( dd.limit.left, dd.offsetX ) )

             });
             $('#nurseView').css({
                left: Math.min( dd.limit.right, Math.max( dd.limit.left, dd.offsetX ) )
            });
          })
          .drag("end",function(ev, dd ){
             var treshold = dd.offsetX;
             var menu = $('#nurseView');
             if(treshold>1712){
                    showing = false;
                    $("#nurseView").animate({"left": "1872px"}, "fast");
                    $(".nursebutton").animate({"left": "1872px"}, "fast");
             }
             else{
                showing = true;
                $("#nurseView").animate({"left": "1595px"}, "fast");
                $(".nursebutton").animate({"left": "1595px"}, "fast");
             }               
          });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think with some proper HTML and CSS you can have one animation instead of 2. They're both going the same direction no matter what, right?

So for the HTML part I would make sure containers actually contain something. Wrapping them up seems to be the proper way.

For the CSS I combined `position: relative` for the main container with `position: absolute` for the inner containers. Check out the fiddle for more changes. Once that was set, I started removing the extra animations.

The actual drag can be done with jQuery UI. Wether you take the whole library or just the draggable part is up to you.

```
/// <reference path="jQuery 1.9.1" />
/// <reference path="jQuery UI 1.9.2" />
// local vars
var showing = false,
    nurseContainer = $('#nurseContainer'),
    nurseButton = $("#nurseContainer a.nursebutton"),
    nurseView = $("#nurseView");

// drag event: jquery ui can filter much for you
nurseContainer.draggable(
    { 
        axis: "x",
        handle: nurseButton,
        containment: nurseView,
        drag: function(ev, ui){
            // small css position correction
            if (ui.position.left <= 50){
                ui.position.left = 50;
            }
        }
    }
);

// click event: with mouseup you don't fire extra events
nurseButton.mouseup(function(){
    if (!showing) {
        showing = true;
        nurseContainer.animate({ left: 50 }, 400);
    } else {
        showing = false;
        nurseContainer.animate({ left: 325 }, 400); // 50 + 275
    }
});
```

Note I used as less stringvalues as possible to keep it clean and readable.
Hope you can finetune to your requirements with this example.

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/tive/AnVfh/

**jQuery UI API** http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/